# Remove my custom attribute code and only show the value in the checkout address summary

Tags: checkout, custom-attributes, checkout-summary

Is there a way to remove my custom attribute code and only show the value?

I created a custom address attribute "special_instructions" and when I add an address in my account section everything works fine.. but when I add an address in the checkout the address summary shows my attribute code and the value.

What can I do?

[image: m]

Comment: Please add your custom address attribute related code. This will definitely help you to sort out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code snippet is responsible for rendering the custom address attributes:

```
<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
    <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
        <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
            <if args="element[attribute].label">
                <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
            </if>
            <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                <if args="element[attribute].value">
                    <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                </if>
            </ifnot>
        </if>
        <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
            <text args="element[attribute]"/>
        </if><br/>
    </each>
</each>
```

As you can see, it checks whether the attribute has a `label` property. if yes, it will show the label. Otherwise, it will show the `value` property.

So I assume you don't have the label property for your custom address attribute.

Comment: Ty Rajeev! I´ll take a look